# Return values of functions

Tags: function, powershell, return-value

I have two functions:

```
Function1
{
    Function2
    return 1
}

Function2
{
    return 0
}
```

After executing `Function1` it should return `1`, but it returns `0`. Why is that?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. What are you expecting Function1 to return and what is it returning?

Comment: after executing Function1 it shoulf return value 1 but it returns value 0.

Comment: How are you calling Function1 and how are you detecting its return value?

Answer (score 11):

PowerShell "return values" don't really work the way you'd be used to from other languages. The important thing to remember is that *all output* is captured and returned. The `return` statement is basically just a logical exit point.

For example:

```
Function Return-Zero {
    return 0
}

Function Return-One {
    Return-Zero
    return 1
}

Return-One
```

Since the return value of `Return-Zero` was not stored in a variable, it is part of the output. Running the above will have the output:

```
0
1
```

...which is probably what you're getting. If you store the return of `Return-Zero` in a variable, it is not part of the output.

```
Function Return-Zero {
    return 0
}

Function Return-One {
    $var = Return-Zero
    return $var
}

Return-One
```

Output of the above is `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem. So do you know of any way to actually return the thing that you want, discarding other outputs. Outputs are hard to capture in your way because you dont know if a statement will return any value or not.

Comment: The actual code would dictate the best way to go about it. If you have an example to post, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it continues to run, and that it only returns 0?  It should return 0 (the return from function 2), then return 1, and exit.

Comment: no it returns 0 and continues to run..if m not wrong sine the Funtion1 has got return 0 from Function2 call it ignores the return 1...is that possible...have i missed something...but when i assign the Function2 cqll in Funtion1 to a variable the funtion1 exits properly...y this strange behaviour...is there a precedence of return value or something...