# Powershell: Can't add attachment to my mail

Tags: powershell, outlook, attachment

I get an exception when trying to add an attachment to a mail: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

I can send mail without attachment add attachment to my template, but can't add. I tried the following ways:

1. ```
   $attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($pathToAttachment) 
   $fMail.Attachments.Add($attach)
   ```
2. I also tried to give a path array instead of a single string to the `Add` method.
3. also tried to set an array to `$fMail.Attachments`

This is my code that i use now

```
$fOutlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$fMail =$fOutlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($pathToTemplate)
$fMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = $mailFrom
$fMail.To = $mailTo
$fMail.Subject = $mailSubject
$fMail.Attachments.Add($pathToAttachment)
```

Thank you for your time.

---

UPDATE

If i am trying to use this logic

```
$myAttachments = $fMail.Attachments 
$myAttachments.Count    # <-- here I get 25
$myAttachments.Add($pathToAttachment)
```

but previous line results in the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." exception.

Why are my my attachments a "null-valued expression" if I can get properties from them?

Comment: what is the FULL error message? powershell normally has a good deal of useful info in such msgs.

Comment: Thank you for  your advise :)  I add additional try/catch and found the following.

Comment: I have seceral functions, one of them add-attachment, so if I use this method I can't then inoke Send method, or call .htmlBody property in other. "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"  it was for fMail.htmlBody call, and if I try to send mail i get Send-Mail: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Send'. But if try to call send method inside the function that add attachments - it works. I cant understand why.

Comment: PLEASE post the full text of the error message IN YOUR QUESTION. also include the actual code you ran to trigger the error - but only as much as is needed to trigger the error. strip away any extraneous code so that helpers can focus on the problem, not on finding what code is actually involved in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found  the answer here
[Return values of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955771/return-values-of-functions)

I did not publish the full code, as I thought it was redundant. But the problem turned out to be in the hidden part.

```
function Add-Attachment{
param($fMail)
$attachments = $fMail.Attachments.Add($pathToAttachment) // the right version (1)
$fMail.Attachments.Add($pathToAttachment) // the wrong version (2)
return $fMail
}

function Send-Mail{
param($fMail)
$fMail.Send
}

   $Mail = Add-Attachment $Mail
   Send-Mail $Mail
```

as indicated in the information provided by the link  that all output is captured and returned. So, when I tried to invoke

Send-Mail $Mail

as I understand, $Mail was no longer an Mail object, but was a collection of elements (Attachments Collection, Mail)

so I stored the attachments collections as variable and now it is not part of the output.